# multiple database connections with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many-through

How can I make a has_many through work with multiple database connections?

I have a database named "master" that holds the location information.  That is updated from a separate application.  Users can have access to many locations, but all the other models are located in another database named "budget".  Here are how the models are setup.

```
# place.rb
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, :through => :places
  has_many :places
end

# location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "master"
  has_many :places
  has_many :users, :through => :places
end
```

When I run commands through irb, I get the following

```
> Location.first.places.create(:user_id => 1)
> #<Place id: 1, user_id: 1, location_id: 1, created_at: "2011-11-28 20:58:43",  updated_at: "2011-11-28 20:58:43">

> Location.first.places
> [#<Place id: 1, user_id: 1, location_id: 1, created_at: "2011-11-28 20:58:43", updated_at: "2011-11-28 20:58:43">]

> Location.first.users
> [#<User id: 1, username: "toby", role: "guest", created_at: "2011-11-28 17:45:40", updated_at: "2011-11-28 17:45:40">

> User.first.locations
> Mysql2::Error: Table 'master.places' doesn't exist: SELECT `locations`.* FROM `locations` INNER JOIN `places` ON `locations`.`id` = `places`.`location_id` WHERE `places`.`user_id` = 1 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'master.places' doesn't exist: SELECT `locations`.* FROM `locations` INNER JOIN `places` ON `locations`.`id` = `places`.`location_id` WHERE `places`.`user_id` = 1
```

I tried adding the current rails env to Place to try and override the default database for place, like this:
    # place.rb
    class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
      establish_connection Rails.env
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :location
    end

```
#database.yml

master:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: master
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: budget_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

That didn't help.  Any ideas?

Comment: you should also post the snippet from your config/database.yml file where you define your databases

Comment: I updated it, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend answered this for me, and I figured it might be of some use to others.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  #establish_connection "master"
  def self.table_name() "master.locations" end
  has_many :places
  has_many :users, :through => :places
end
```

Comment: in my case, database is on external server and this solution doesnt work..

Answer (score 2):

The answer works for me, but I use this version in my relation table:

```
self.table_name = "master.locations"
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone reading this a few years later, please be advised Rails 7 has introduced an explicit `disable_joins: true` option to `has_one` and `has_many`.

ref: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#handling-associations-with-joins-across-databases