# Encountering relationship issues with ActiveRecord has_many through on two different databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to setup a `has_many :through` relationship over two different databases and encountering an issue.

My models are as follow:

*company*:

```
# this model lives in database main_db
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_custom_plans
  has_many :custom_plans, through: :company_custom_plans
end
```

*custom_plan*

```
# this model lives in database other_app_db
class CustomPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_custom_plans
  has_many :companies, through: :company_custom_plans
end
```

*joint model*:

```
# this model lives in other_app_db
class CompanyCustomPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :custom_plan
  belongs_to :company
end

### Schema ###
#  create_table "company_custom_plans", force: :cascade do |t|
#    t.integer "company_id",     limit: 4, null: false
#    t.integer "custom_plan_id", limit: 4, null: false
#  end
```

So it works quite great on the Company model but when trying to use this relation on the CustomPlan I'm getting an error because the has_many :through looks for the `company_custom_plans` in `main_db` instead of `other_app_db`

example:

```
ccp = CompanyCustomPlan.create!(company: company, custom_plan: custom_plan)
company.company_custom_plans == [ccp] # true
company.custom_plans == [custom_plan] # true
custom_plan.company_custom_plans == [ccp] # true

custom_plan.companies # error
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'main_db.company_custom_plans' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `company_custom_plans`
```

I tried to play with the different options of has_many :through (like setting `source: 'company'`) but cannot figure out how to make this work.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the SQL statements generated for both `company.custom_plans` and `custom_plan.companies`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to force the `has_many :through` to use the right database following this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302482/multiple-database-connections-with-has-many-through).

```
class CompanyCustomPlan < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = "#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database}.company_custom_plans"

  belongs_to :custom_plan
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Answer (score 3):

When naming join models for `has_many through:` associations (or models in general that have compound names) you should follow the format of `SingularSingular` for the model and `singular_plural` for the table. So you should name the model `CompanyCustomPlan` and the table `company_custom_plans`. This is different from `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

For example:

```
class User
  has_many :user_courses
  has_many :courses, though: :user_courses
end

class Course
  has_many :user_courses
  has_many :users, though: :user_courses
end

class UserCourse
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end
```

This will correctly map the association to the UserCourse class. If we had used `has_many :users_courses` we would get `NameError: uninitialized constant Users::Courses` due to the way that ActiveRecord derives the class name from the association - plural words are interpreted as modules!

You can of course override this by providing the `class_name` option but following the convention may be a better idea in the first place unless you have a good reason not to.

You can of course use a use completely different name for the join model if there is something which describes the domain better - for example   `Enrollment` instead of `UserCourse`.

Comment: thanks but that's not it. I forgot to mention the two model lives in two different databases and thus updated the question, I also singularized the model following your advice !